# Resize HTML5 input control in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: javascript, css, html, windows-8

I am writing a Windows 8 Store App using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS. On one screen of the application I have several HTML5 input controls to collect data from the user, defined in my HTML file like the one below:

```
<input id="priceInput" type="number" />
```

The input textboxes render and behave as they should, however a few of them are far too long for the data they capture. Is there a way to set the length of the input textbox either in HTML or CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the width with CSS:

```
#priceInput {
    width: 100px
}
```

Comment: The CSS code did the trick. I thought I had tried that before and it didn't work, but maybe I am thinking of something else.

Comment: I don't think you can use the size attribute. I got this error in Visual Studio: "Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'size' is not a valid attribute of element 'input'."

Comment: @StevenBall That makes sense; the attribute is considered obsolete since this type of stuff is expected to be found in your CSS.

Comment: And keep in mind that you don't have to size each by its ID. If you use a style rule like input[type=text] { width: 100px; } then it will apply to all of them. You might want to scope the rule to a single page too by using one like .pageName input[type=text] { width: 100%; }. Hope that helps.